# How to get a screenshot of a CATiledLayer based TilingView

Tags: ios, screenshot, catiledlayer, uigraphicscontext

I'm trying in my app to take a screenshot of the current screen contents, where my TilingView (based on CATiledLayers) displays a number of transparent large tiled images.
Also I added some subViews to the TilingView, which are magically captured in the screenshot, however the underlying contents of the TilingView is not captured!??

The following code-snippets takes a snapshot of the visible screen, which seems to work well for a NON CATiledLayer based view-hierarchy, but unfortunately doesn't work for my setup. Even if I pass the topmost superview of the TilingView (being the actual UIViewController.view), I see only in my snapshot the StatusBar, NavigationBar, the TilingViews subViews and the TabBar, but again NOT the TilingViews contents.

```
- (UIImage*)captureView:(UIView *)viewToCapture {
    CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Does anybody know or see here what I'm missing? Do I need to delve deeper into the CG-related display stack with some, for me, unknown CG-API calls? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By searching some more in StackOverflow I've found code which seems to do what I wanted. Basically I need to change the above method into:

```
- (UIImage*)captureView:(UIView*)viewToCapture {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewToCapture.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [viewToCapture drawViewHierarchyInRect:viewToCapture.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Thanks go to the question/answer at: [How to get a screenshot of a view containing GPUImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218126/how-to-get-a-screenshot-of-a-view-containing-gpuimageview)